# Why is Firebase silently converting my Longs to Integers?

Tags: java, firebase

Under certain circumstances, I am seeing some surprising behavior with Firebase's Java API: it's returning instances of java.lang.Integer when I'm dealing with java.lang.Long. Here's an example JUnit test case:

```java
public class LongsTest extends TestCase {
  public void testSetLong() throws Exception {
    Firebase firebase = new Firebase("http://www.example.com");
    firebase.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
      @Override public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot s) {}
      @Override public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot s, String p) {}
      @Override public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot s, String p) {}
      @Override public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot s, String p) {
        Map<String, Object> map = s.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String,Object>>() {});
        System.out.println(map.get("key").getClass());
      }
      @Override public void onCancelled() {}
    });
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("key", new Long(15));
    firebase.child("foo").setValue(map);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

Running this code prints out `class java.lang.Integer`! Firebase obviously still knows I have a Long somewhere in its code, because changing the body of `onChildAdded` to this:

```java
Map<String,Object> map2 = (Map<String,Object>)s.getValue();
System.out.println(map2.get("key").getClass())
```

Correctly prints out `class java.lang.Long`. What's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase dev here. It's actually a pretty subtle behavior, and has to to do with the underlying json library (Jackson) used by the Firebase SDK. By default, Firebase stores both ints and longs as longs internally. So, when you ask for the data back, by default you will get a Long.

However, using the GenericTypeIndicator overrides Firebase's default behavior, and goes directly to Jackson's default behavior when trying to marshall into the specified type. In this case, when Jackson encounters a number that it can fit into an Integer, that's what it does. When it encounters a number that is too large to fit into an Integer, it returns a Long.

As an exercise, try changing

```
map.put("key", new Long(15));
```

to

```
map.put("key", (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1)
```

and you should see the resulting class is a Long.

The rationale for this is that GenericTypeIndicator is a way to override the Firebase defaults. By using a GenericTypeIndicator that specifies Object, you're leaving it up to the underlying deserializer to pick a concrete type. In this case, if you have all Longs in the dictionary, you could do Map< String, Long >. If not, it's safe to convert any Integers you come across to Longs. The values that don't fit into an Integer will be returned as Longs already. For more information on Jackson, you can find their (admittedly a little sparse) documentation here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDocumentation

Comment: Interesting, I guess I'll avoid using GenericTypeIndicator for my mixed-type collections so I don't need to write special code to cast all the results to the right type.

Comment: If your mixed-type collections map to a POJO, or a collection of POJOs, you can try doing something like s.getValue(MyObject.class);, or s.getValue(new GenericTypeIndicator<Map<String, MyObject>>() {});